# Angular Service for storing values

Tags: angular, auth0

I may be doing this wrong (which is probably why it's not working :) ), but I'm trying to tie into my auth service (Auth0) and then store the values and make them available to other parts of the application.

here's my auth service:

```js
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService as Auth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-angular';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService implements OnInit{
  private _isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
  private _token: any = null;
  private _user: any = null;

  constructor(public auth0: Auth0) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('here');
    this.auth0.isAuthenticated$.subscribe((result) => this._isAuthenticated = result);
    this.auth0.idTokenClaims$.subscribe((token) => this._token = token);
    this.auth0.user$.subscribe((user) => {
      this._user = user;
    });
  }

  public getUser(): any {
    console.log('getUser');
    return this._user;
  }

  public getToken(): string | null {
    if (this.isAuthenticated()) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return this._token;
    }
  }

  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return this._isAuthenticated;
  }
}
```

A couple of things:

1. `console.log('here');` in the `ngOnInit()` method is never called.
2. all of my "getter" methods are returning `null` for the private variables.

If I perform one of the subscriptions that you see in the `ngOnInit()` elsewhere in my application, the data is returned fine.

Also, I could create a line such as:

```js
public user$ = this.auth0.user$;
```

and subscribe to it elsewhere in my application, but that kind of defeats the purpose.

My goal is to have a single auth service where I can perform other auth/user functions.

How do I do this? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: [`OnInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) applies to directives/components, not services as far as I can tell.

Comment: Replace OnInit() by contructor() and see what happens.

Comment: Yup. I moved the subscriptions to the constructor and now it works.  THanks!